# Animated GIFs keep screen from sleeping

Tags: windows-7, display

I have my dual-monitor setup (Windows 7 OS) set to sleep after 20 minutes of inactivity. This works fine until I leave an animated GIF up, in which case it never sleeps.

I can reproduce this 100% of the time. But when I Google for it, nobody else seems to have this problem.

The first question must be "Am I delusional?" But the second just as surely must be "What the hell is going on and how the hell can I prevent this behavior?"

Note that I already know I can just never leave an animated GIF open, but sometimes I get distracted. OK, I *often* get distracted.

Also, this has nothing to do with porn, so please save your jokes. ^_^

Comment: If the GIFs are showing in a browser, you should be able to disable animations by default: search for `disable GIF animation`.

Comment: Thanks, but that's throwing out the baby with the bathwater. I viewed the GIF because I wanted to see it.

Comment: In that case it comes down to personal discipline. I presume that animated GIFs are treated in the same way as videos, where you don't want to have to interact every 20 minutes in order to keep watching.

Comment: If it *is* being viewed in a browser (rather than IrfanView or other A-V application), try a different browser to test the issue (e.g. if you're using Chrome, try IE or Firefox). No, it may not resolve your issue, but you'll find out the cause.